# ExecutorService.Submit(Callable<T>) is returning null value for Future<T> object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, executorservice

I'm using `ExecutorService` to spawn threads for performing different tasks. When the `submit(Callable<T>)` method is made, it should return a `Future<T>` object. Instead, it is returning null. As a result, when `Future<T>.get()` method is called, it will fail with `NullPointerException`.

Has any one faced this problem? Or, am I doing something wrong?

```
ArrayList<Boolean> resultsList = new ArrayList<Boolean> ();
ExecutorService excutorService  = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(ClassImplementingCallable myClassImplementingCallable : listOfClassesImplementingCallable) {
    resultsList.add( excutorService.submit( myClassImplementingCallable ) );
}
excutorService.shutdown();
for ( Future< Boolean > result : resultList ) {
    result.get(); // getting exception here..
}
```

Comment: Please don't use HTML tags in your questions.

Comment: what are the values returned by the `callable`?

Comment: Did you figure out what was going on??

Answer (score 3):

What is surprising is that you could compile your code: you are trying to add some `Future<Boolean>` to a `List<Boolean>`...

`resultsList` should be declared as:

```
List<Future<Boolean>> resultsList = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>> ();
```

Apart from that, you should not receive a NPE with your code as it is, unless one of the `myClassImplementingCallable` in `listOfClassesImplementingCallable` is null.

Comment: Sure, I'l check that. Thanks for ur reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `List<Future<Boolean>> resultsList = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>();`

```
    for ( Future< Boolean > result : resultList ) {
    result.get(); // getting exception here..
}
```

resultsList is not an array in your code